# PrimeFaces dataTable - how to scroll to its bottom on change

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces dataTable that gets refreshed on actions of various controls of the page. (I use `p:ajax update="myDataTable"` ..)

I have a JavaScript method calling `row.scrollIntoView(true)` on the last table row. (The nicer `row.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(true)` seems to be available only in Chrome.)

Well, I need the table to scroll to the last entry on such a refresh. Is there any event I can listen to? Or is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `p:ajax` tag has an `oncomplete` attribute. You could use:

```
<p:ajax update="myDataTable" oncomplete="yourJsMethod()"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use JQuery for (it's supported by PrimeFaces natively):

```
function scrollToBottom() {
    $('.ui-datatable-scrollable-body').scrollTop(100000)
}
```

Next,

```
<p:ajax update="myDataTable" oncomplete="scrollToBottom()"/>
```